# Comma after introductory words, phrases, clauses: unacceptable, obligatory or optional?

Tags: commas, prepositional-phrases

I am no native speaker and always confused about the comma in introductory phrases, in particular in prepositional phrases. Is there any hard rule when a comma must be set? If I make a google search for certain phrases, I often find both variants. Typical examples where I am not sure whether a comma must be set are:

> - First[ly][,] I must phone mother
> - In this case[,] we must...
> - For simple problems[,] the algorithm...
> - From Lemma 1.2[,] we obtain...
> - For a typical user[,] the algorithm...
> - In our theory[,] we...
> - A dark line on the horizon[,] the mountain range we were headed for seemed somehow not as threatening as when we had started out on the trip.
> - Avidly reading her novel[,] Jane did not notice that her stop was approaching.
> - To be sure[,] it is not easy to see a solution.
> - When you get to Rome[,] give me a ring.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Larry Trask’s advice](https://web.archive.org/web/20111227082057/https://www.informatics.sussex.ac.uk/department/docs/punctuation/node13.html) in cases like this is to see what happens if you remove from the sentence the words marked off by the comma. If you are left with a meaningful sentence, then the comma is appropriate. If no meaningful sentence remains, you don’t need the comma.

Comment: Trask is primarily talking about paired "bracketting commas" delineating non-essential clauses. Near the end of that link he covers cases where the "supplementary clause" appears at the beginning or end of a sentence (with a notional comma assumed before or after the clause). The fact that you can still have a meaningful sentence without the clause doesn't mean you **must always** enclose it in commas - just that you **can**.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Quite so. Knowing the dangers of selective quotation, I hoped Boris would go to the source.

Comment: I think there's a tendency to use the comma, notwithstanding RiMMER's position. I personally would change your *comma is appropriate* to *comma may well be appropriate*, but really I think it's largely a matter of style in OP's specific context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I used to be a minimalist in punctuation, but am  swinging back slightly in the opposite direction.

Comment: Oh dear - does that make me a dinosaur? I still think providing readability doesn't suffer, *less is more* in punctuation as in so many things.

Comment: "The fact that you can still have a meaningful sentence without the clause doesn't mean**,** you must always enclose it in commas - just that you **can**." <-- not so, as illustrated ;-)

Answer (score 15):

[Comma sense—a fun-damental guide to punctuation](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0739465031) suggest to use the comma to set off introductory elements, which are reported to be:

- an adverb: *First, I need to call my girlfriend.*
- a prepositional phrase: *After dinner, let's go to see a movie.*
- an appositive: *A stumbling giggler, Lumpy was hardly prepared for the relay baton suddenly being thrust upon him.*
- a participial phrase
- an infinitive phrase: *To be honest, I think you are over-reacting.*
- a dependent clause: *If you are going to leave this room, I am not going to call you anymore.*

This is an example used by that guide to show what happens if you don't use the comma after an introductory element:

> After retiring my wife, my parents, the kids, and I plan to travel around the country.

Comment: "After retiring my wife, my parents, the kids, and I plan to travel around the country." - um, so? My wife, my parents, the kids, and I plan to travel. I see no problems with that. Conversely, if you remove the comma after "wife" then it will become "after retiring my wife" what will happen? "My parents, the kids, and I plan to travel". Again, all clear. No comma needed after "retiring".

Comment: _After retiring my wife, my parents, the kids, and I plan to travel around the country_ would be equivalent to _after I retire my wife, I plan to travel around the country with my parents and the kids._ That is different from _after retiring, my wife, my parents, the kids, and I plan to travel around the country_, which would be equivalent to _after I retire, I plan to travel around the country with my wife, my parents, and the kids_.

Comment: Also, _retire_ without object has a meaning, which is different from _retire_ with object. (_I will retire in 2030._ _The general retired all his troops._)

Comment: "After retiring my wife, my parents, the kids, and I plan to travel around the country would be equivalent to after I retire my wife, I plan to travel around the country with my parents and the kids." - No, not to me. If reading it your way why stopping with the wife? I would get "after I retire my wife, my parents and the kids" then "and I plan to travel around the country with my parents and the kids". I cannot start with "and I", so the whole sentence makes no sense. If I read it as "after I retire my wife, my parents, the kids, and I" then "plan to travel" still make no sense.

Comment: But a simpler solution would be to say "After retiring I together with my wife, my parents and the kids plan to travel..." ;-)

Comment: Given the book's authors use the Oxford comma and given the position of _and_, the object of _retiring_ can just be _my wife_, or the sentence would start with _after retiring my wife and my parents_ or _after retiring my wife, my parents, and my kids_. In the latter case, the sentence would not continue with _and I plan_.

Comment: The simpler solution doesn't show what happens when a comma is missing. The book doesn't want to give simple sentences, either for being funny, or showing how important is using the proper punctuation.

Answer (score 8):

After Understanding English Grammar by Martha Kolln, [grammar.ccc.commnet.edu ...](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/commas_intro.htm) advises the following:

**Commas and Introductory Elements**

1. When a sentence begins with an adverbial clause, put a comma after it.

> Although we had reviewed the film twice before, we never noticed these
> details about the shooting.
>
> As the day drew to a smoky end, the firefighters put out the last of
> the embers.

[To go beyond the basic improvements that we have already started work on, we will need to raise more funds.]

2. It is permissible, even commonplace, to omit a comma after most brief introductory elements — a prepositional phrase, an adverb, or a noun phrase:

> Yesterday afternoon we sat around waiting for Bill to arrive.
>
> By evening we had become impatient.
>
> Jauntily he walked into the hall.

[To go further we will need to raise more funds.]

3. When a prepositional phrase expands to more than three words, say, or becomes connected to yet another prepositional phrase, the use of a comma will depend on the writer's sense of the rhythm and flow of the sentence.

> After his nap Figueroa felt better.
>
> After his long nap in the backyard hammock, Figueroa felt better.

4. When an introductory adverbial element seems to modify the entire sentence and not just the verb or some single element in the rest of the sentence [ie this is a pragmatic marker rather than a true adverbial function] put a comma after it.

> Fortunately, no one in the bridal party was in that car.
>
> Sadly, the old church was completely destroyed.
>
> On the other hand, someone obviously was badly injured.

[To be honest, I think that the Government has relaxed lockdown regulations too early.]

5. Don't allow a brief introductory element to merge with something following it in a way that can confuse your reader. Try reading the following sentences without their commas:

> Until the spring course lists will not be published.
>
> Until the spring, course lists will not be published.

..................

> Inside the gym was brightly lighted and clean.
>
> Inside, the gym was brightly lighted and clean.

6. When a sentence begins with an Absolute Phrase or an adverbial Infinitive Phrase, put a comma after it. (If the infinitive phrase is acting as a noun and is the subject of the sentence, be careful not to put a comma between the subject and its verb: "To believe in one's self is a good thing.")

> Their headpieces flapping wildly about their ears, the priestesses
> began their eerie chant.
>
> To escape with our lives, we would have to run for the exits.

Comment: Do these patterns differ between British and American usage?

Comment: Kolln is an American grammarian. I'm British, and agree unreservedly with every point she makes.

Comment: What about the introductory phrase "Because of XYZ". My apologies, I don't know what phrase that would be called

Comment: 'Because of' is probably best classed as a compound (two-orthographic-word) preposition. Here is an example of a sentence starting with this preposition from [OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/because-of): _Because of his wife(’s) being there, I said nothing about it._  There is an obvious correspondence between the inclusion of the comma and normal speech pattern. With 'Because of the war we were not allowed to have the bells rung', where the introductory PP is short, I'd say the comma (and the pause many associate with it) is optional.