# When writing user stories, should there be a comma after "As a User", and before "I want"?

Tags: commas, programming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comma after introductory phrases](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52091/comma-after-introductory-phrases)

Agile software development often encourages people to write up user stories using a given formula. The formula is: "As a User I want to something so that reason for something".
Some example of this formula put a comma after "As a User", some do not.

So which is correct and why:

"As a Visitor I want to view your products so that I can buy something"

Or

"As a Visitor, I want to view your products so that I can buy something"

Comment: mhoroszowski, I think you've asked a good question, but there is already a good answer to it by kiamlaluno in [question #52091](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52091/comma-after-introductory-phrases).  In your examples I'd use a comma after *User* or *Visitor* as suggested there.

Answer (score 3):

I vote for using the comma. *As a Visitor* is an introductory clause, and as such I think it needs to be followed by a comma. See [this explanation (point #2):](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/607/02/)

> Use commas after introductory a) clauses, b) phrases, or c) words that come before the main clause.
>
> a. Common starter words for introductory clauses that should be followed by a comma include *after, although, **as**, because, if, since, when, while.*
>
> > While I was eating, the cat scratched at the door.
> >
> > Because her alarm clock was broken, she was late for class.
> >
> > If you are ill, you ought to see a doctor.
> >
> > When the snow stops falling, we'll shovel the driveway.

Comment: You certainly wouldn't want anyone to read it like this:  "While I was eating the cat...", which is why your answer is correct.