# is the usage of this comma correct?

Tags: commas

Can you please tell me if my comma in the following statement is correct?  Should there be a comma after "questions" as it is below?

> Should you have any questions, please feel free to contact me at the
>   number below.

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a duplicate of [Comma after introductory phrases](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52091/comma-after-introductory-phrases).

Answer (score 1):

Punctuation is a matter of style, so you should consult your style guide.  If you consult some of the better-known ones, you'll find that they recommend that a comma follow introductory adverbial clauses like "Should you have any questions."