# Is the comma here needed?

Tags: meaning, grammar, punctuation, commas, conjunctions

So I just saw this quote:

"If anyone needs me, I'll be in the corner crying."

Is the comma here needed? And if so, why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comma after introductory phrases](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52091/comma-after-introductory-phrases)

Comment: @Rathony Not in this case, I don't think.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it is needed.

It's all about representing what you would do when you speak, with a comma indicating a pause.

If you were speaking your sentence, you would pause after "If anyone needs me".  Therefore, you need the comma.

Comment: And the reason for the down vote?

Comment: Because what you are saying is a common misconception of what a comma is. The comma is represented by a pause in speech, but a pause in speech is not represented by the comma.

Comment: @Max Thanks. What's your source?

Comment: Every source dealing with punctuation. There are many style guides. One of the most popular of such is the Chicago Manual of Style.

Comment: @Max Thanks. I'll check it out. How would you have answered this question?

Comment: No problem. I would have said that if the dependant clause is before the independent clause, a comma should be used to separate them. In fact, I'd also point out that there should also be a comma before 'crying' - as it is used as a gerund here, meaning it forms a list with the verb 'be'; all list items are separated with commas.