# Can I start a sentence with "For the last ten years...?"

Tags: commas, syntactic-analysis, prepositions

Can I start a sentence with "For the last ten years...?" and do I need to put a comma after that.
For instance, "For the last ten years, I have been doing my PhD".
I am grateful for your help.

Comment: I think it's better to say *for the past ten years...*

Comment: I agree with @Ustanak, i.e., "For the past ten years, I have been doing my PhD."

Comment: 'For the preceding decade, I've been undertaking my PhD.'

Comment: 'The whole of these past ten years has been spent on my PhD.'

Comment: 'I've been working towards this PhD since 2006.'

Comment: Just don't end that sentence with *student*.

Comment: @Jim ~ hahaha..

Comment: For the comma question, you might look [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52091/comma-after-introductory-phrases)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes you can, but a comma is optional.**

- For the last ten years, I have been doing my PhD.

"For the last ten years" is a introductory prepositional phrase, and "I have been doing my PhD" is an independent clause.  A comma is optional to separate introductory prepositional phrase from the rest of the sentence.  In this case, I *would* use a comma, because the introductory phrase isn't required for the sentence and is there to add detail to it.

Comment: I'm reasonably sure that "For the last ten years" is an [introductory prepositional phrase](http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000074.htm) , not a clause.

Comment: PS: I didn't DV you. I almost never DV unless the Q or A is absolutely awful.

Comment: @Gandalf So the comma could actually be left out.  I will edit.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a comma if there is no confusion and the sentence is short.  "For the past ten years I've been ill."

Comment: As the other answer suggests, I think you are supposed to have a comma. However, it is common to see native speakers omit the comma in their writings... but it's common to see native speakers butcher punctuation in all manner of ways.

Comment: -1 The usage of a comma here is nothing to do with either confusion or length of sentence: it is to do with separating the clauses for ease of reading and *immediate* understanding, as indicated in the other example.

Comment: As indicated by @Gandalf, because the independent phrase is short you can drop the comma. If the independent phrase was long or complicated for some reason, the comma helps. As it stands, putting a pause between "For the last ten years" and "I have been working on my PhD" would be awkward if you were to speak it aloud and is somewhat awkward written.