# Comma after "Unfortunately" in the beginning of a sentence.

Tags: commas

Here, Cambridge doesn't use a comma.  I am confused.
Example in Cambridge Dictionary:
Unfortunately we can't come this evening after all.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/worterbuch/englisch/unfortunately

On different pages i found some rules telling there needs to be a comma.
Examples follow:

We do usually put a comma after adverbs like 'unfortunately'. They are called 'sentence adverbs' because they modify the whole sentence and often give the opinion of the speaker/writer.

A parenthetical phrase adding detail to the main clause. Initially placed parentheticals are normally set off by a comma.

Cause I'm studying for my Level 2 graduation, i want going crazy reading
here and there comma rules followed by looking in the Cambridge Dictionary
without finding them there.

HELP me out please !

Comment: How does "unfortunately", in such a case, differ from "however"?

Comment: Studying Business English, unfortunately is more polite or formal. Prevered to be used in a letter of apologize. For example:

Unfortunately, the ordered goods are out of stock.

Comment: Can you accept answer if handles the question? See: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comma after introductory phrases](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52091/comma-after-introductory-phrases)

Answer (score 7):

The Oxford Manual of Style has this to say about sentence adverbs:

> Adverbs and adverbial phrases that comment on the whole sentence, such as *therefore*, *perhaps*, *of course*, are often enclosed in commas, but this is not a fixed rule. Sense may be altered by the comma's placement or presence. Consider the following:
>
> - We'll go to Cornwall, perhaps in the spring. (perhaps then)
> - We'll go to Cornwall perhaps, in the Spring. (perhaps elsewhere)
> - Again she refused to speak. (once more)
> - Again, she refused to speak. (in addition)
> - The ship's captain ordered a change, of course. (indeed?)

In your particular example, the use of a comma would appear to be optional (and therefore a matter of style), since it doesn't alter the meaning.

> - Unfortunately we can't come this evening after all.
> - Unfortunately, we can't come this evening after all.

These both seem to mean the same thing, with a slight change of emphasis.