# Yesterday, I met Susan at the grocer's. - Is the comma here incorrect?

Tags: commas, word-order

Revising to the exam again...

In a chapter dedicated to something else, in the answers to an exercise, there was such a sentence:

> Yesterday I met Susan at the grocer's. / I met Susan at the grocer's yesterday.

Problem is, when I was doing this exercise, I wrote this sentence in this way:

> Yesterday, I met Susan at the greengrocer's.

I'm very doubtful about this comma.

I must confess: I don't know (or remember) any rule that would say if the comma here is necessary? acceptable? Incorrect? I must confess: When I was learning English in school, I consciously skipped learning all those comma rules and instead I was relying on my intuition, which, I think, was becoming better and better the more English texts I was reading and the more commas my teacher was crossing out or putting in my tests with her red pen.

And now, my intuition strongly tells me that the natural order of words in English, in case of this sentence, is:

> I met Susan at the grocer's yesterday.

So, if I put "yesterday" at the beginning of this sentence, I'm inverting the usual order of words, thus necessitating a comma. (In a manner similar to conditional sentences: The usual order is "blah1 if blah2", so if I'm inverting it, I must put a comma: "if blah2, (then) blah1" but not "if blah2 (then) blah1".)

Is my intuition correct here? (I suppose it's not, since this would imply this book has another error, and while that's not impossible, I find it more likely that I'm wrong.) Which rule is appropriate here?

EDIT: Since someone marked my question a dupe of a couple of other questions that deal with possessive forms of store names: To make it clear: My question has NOTHING to do with store names and possessives! It is all about the comma after "yesterday" - this "grocer's" part is just to provide a full sentence example of my concern.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I don't know how could this question be a dupe of mine, I'm asking for the comma after "yesterday", this has nothing to do with this greengrocer's, have you even read my question...?

Comment: Ooops! Closevote retracted. Which means I *can't* now closevote again for a different reason. Your question is essentially "Primarily Opinion-Based", in that there is no "rule" for whether or not to set off adverbial ***yesterday*** (regardless of whether you put it before, after, or *within* the main clause it modifies) - it's a stylistic choice which should be primarily governed by whether or not the comma reflects *a pause in **speech*** (which isn't "fixed" - it's up to the speaker whether and where he might pause).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: it should *not* be closed as opinion-based. A much more helpful answer is that the comma is optional grammatically, as explained by the answer to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/418536/comma-after-unfortunately-in-the-beginning-of-a-sentence?rq=1), which I'm voting to close it as a duplicate of (although I suspect there's probably a closer duplicate).

Comment: I upvoted your comment (I agree it's bound to be a dup of *something*), but I'm not sure "this one" is it.  It seems to me there could be a difference between a "sentence adverb", such as  ***Unfortunately** I met Susan at the grocer's*, and an "ordinary" adverb (such as ***yesterday***, here) that specifically modifies just the actual verb in the target clause.

Comment: Duplicate of [comma after introductory phrases](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52091/comma-after-introductory-phrases).