# The word order in sentences with 'once a week'

Tags: word-order

I wonder if *once a week* can be used at the beginning of the sentence and if yes, whether it should be followed with a comma. I tried browsing the Internet and Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary, but I haven't found examples with *once a week* used at the beginning of a sentence.

Is the following sentence correct?

> Once a week, my sister and I go to a dance club.

Comment: It's quite common to begin a sentence with "Once a week".

Comment: And do you use use a comma if it is at the beginning of the sentence?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comma after introductory phrases](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52091/comma-after-introductory-phrases). I'd use the comma with 'Once a week, my sister and I go to a dance club.' but not with 'We don't eat fish or seafood too often. Once a week we have a fish pie, maybe.'

Answer (score 1):

> READING WITH UNDERSTANDING, Intermediate 2 - Book 1 - Page 5
>   https://books.google.com/books?isbn=979413175X K. Methold - 1969 -
>   ‎Preview «**Once a week** I will get up in the middle of the night and
>   shout «Stop, thief! Stop, thief !» The police will come. Everyone will
>   think I am a good watchman». And this is what he did. For six nights a
>   week he slept all night, but on the seventh night he got up and
>   shouted «Stop, thief! Stop, thief!» and blew his whistle. The police
>   soon came and said, «Where is the thief, old _nian?» «I frightened him
>   away», the old man said. «You are a good watchman and you are brave»,
>   the police said ...
>
> Once a Cop, Always a Cop: Why Me? - Page 33
>   https://books.google.com/books?isbn=1452591288 Lawrence LaRose - 2014
>   - ‎Preview Some people illegally crossed over into neighboring countries like Surinam, Venezuela and Brazil in the hours of darkness,
>   in purchasing band goods. Our household did not miss these band items.
>   The canned goods were not frequently bought by my parents. And we
>   survived off of farinaceous meals as: rice; flour; sago; cassava and
>   various types of ground provisions from mom's kitchen garden. **Once a
>   week** my dad on his way home from the night shift will bring home fresh
>   fish from ...

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I do appreciate it. :)