# Comma usage after the start of a sentence beginning with time

Tags: punctuation, commas, prepositional-phrases

It has been an ongoing debate in my office among managers that there should be a comma used after a statement of time.

Ex.

At 1135 Hrs., (Subject) Was observed doing something that he shouldn't have.

It is this comma after the abbreviated hours we are having a debate over. Is it proper to put it there or is it not needed in this instance?

Comment: Do you work in a police station?

Comment: LOL, i was expecting that question, but no, I do not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comma after introductory phrases](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52091/comma-after-introductory-phrases) (see kiamlaluno's answer, and the Kolln article). Though the use of Hrs is unusual in civilian life, and the period after Hrs can lead to messy double-punctuation ('BrE' tends to leave off periods where ambiguity doesn't ensue). // Conclusion: << At 11:35, X was observed doing something that they shouldn't have been doing. >>

Answer (score -1):

I would say a comma is required, since one could view "At 11:35" as a dependent clause.
This would be apparent by rephrasing the sentence:

> (Subject) was observed doing something that he shouldn't have (at 11:35).

A dependent clause preceding an independent clause must be separated by a comma (see rule 4a, [grammarbook.com](https://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/commas.asp)).