# Is "As a member of a rescue team" a dependent clause and does it therefore warrant a comma after it?

Tags: commas, dependent-clause

I want to know whether the sentence

> As a member of the rescue team, I had a terrifying experience.

is correct with the comma after the "as"-clause.

From my understanding it boils down to the question whether the phrase "As a member of the rescue team" is a *dependent clause*. [Other questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52091/comma-after-introductory-phrases) tackle other clauses (like "in"- or "for"-phrases), but I want to know whether "as"-clauses are dependent

If so, rule 2 from [COMMA SUTRA: 13 rules for using commas](https://www.businessinsider.com.au/a-guide-to-proper-comma-use-2013-9?r=US&IR=T) applies and the comma is correct.

Comment: Regardless of anything else, it's a dangling modifier. As it's written, it's saying that **your experience** (not you) was a member of the rescue team. So, no matter what you do, you should rephrase it.

Comment: @JasonBassford Fair point, Jason. I have updated the sample sentence accordingly. But my question stays: Is the phrase a dependent clause?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comma after introductory phrases](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52091/comma-after-introductory-phrases)

Comment: I'd class the introductory element as a (prepositional) phrase here. [CED_Grammar Today](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/as-and-as-expressions/as) has: '**As** as a preposition ... We use _as_ with a noun to refer to the role or purpose of a person or thing:

_I worked as a waiter when I was a student. Most of us did._ / [Collins](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/as): **as** prep 13. in the role of; being: _as his friend, I am probably biased._ // Compare _For an Elbonian, she's not so bad._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's a dependent clause—and, because it's going first, there should be a comma after it.

From ["Commas with Subordinate Clauses—A Reader’s Question"](https://theeditorsblog.net/2014/07/30/commas-with-subordinate-clauses-a-readers-question/) at The Editor's Blog, Beth Hill says the following:

> **An adverbial clause often starts with a subordinating conjunction.** A short list of subordinating conjunctions:
>
> although
>       after
>       as
>       because
>       before
>       once
>       since
>       though
>       until
>       when
>       while
>
> **A subordinate clause that stands alone is a sentence fragment . . .** While we can use dependent clauses as sentence fragments, most of the time we don’t. We usually pair them with at least one independent clause and create sentences . . . Independent clauses often come first in our text, but putting dependent clauses first gives us variety in sentence construction . . .
>
> When an adverbial dependent clause comes *before* the independent clause, we put a comma after the dependent clause (between the clauses). We don’t have to give any consideration to the topic of essential or nonessential—**when the dependent clause comes before the independent, use a comma to separate them**.

---

Note that it's a dependent clause because it wouldn't make sense on its own *unless* it were in response to what somebody else said:

> "As a member of the rescue team."
> "Sorry, what?"

*but*

> "In what capacity did have a terrifying experience?"
> "As a member of the rescue team."

In short, in order for it to be meaningful in any way, it has to have context—either within a dialogue or linked to an independent clause in the same sentence.

---

In order to address some comments, I interpret *as* in this sentence in the same sense as *because* or *since*.

From Merriam-Webster's [seventh sense](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as#h2) of the conjunction:

> **7** : for the reason that : BECAUSE, SINCE
> // stayed home *as* she had no car

I also take there to be an elided (but implied) verb.

Therefore, the sentence could be rephrased like this:

> (Because / Since) [I was] a member of the rescue team, I had a terrifying experience.

---

It's also possible to interpret *as* in Merriam-Webster's [fifth sense](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as#h2):

> **5** : WHILE, WHEN
> // spilled the milk *as* she got up

Or:

> (While / When) [I was] a member of the rescue team, I had a terrifying experience.

---

In either of these interpretations, *as* functions as part of a subordinate clause in a synonymous sense with one of the other words.

Comment: 'As a member of the rescue team' is a phrase. This 'as' is 'in my capacity as', not the 'while' or 'because' found with clauses.

Comment: Some might call this a verbless subordinate clause consisting of a prepositional phrase, but most would, I think, just call it a prepositional phrase. The page you link to only discusses what they call the subordinating conjunction _as_ (i.e., when the object is a verbal clause), which this isn’t – even in traditional grammar where _as_ can function as a conjunction, this use of _as_ is purely prepositional. Simple PPs often do not to take commas if they’re short, whereas clauses usually always take commas; this one is probably long enough that a comma is advisable in both cases.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I interpret the meaning of the phrase to be synonymous with *(Because  / Since) [I was] a member of the rescue team*. From Merriam-Webster's sense 7 of the [conjunction](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as#h2): "7 : for the reason that : BECAUSE, SINCE // *stayed home as she had no car*." Or, to change the order of the words, *as she had no car, she stayed home*. In short, I consider the verb to be elided.

Comment: If you put _both_ interpretations in the answer (ie add the 'comments'), I'll reverse (not nullify) the downvote. But _all_ 'introductory elements', including clauses (kiamlaluno sensibly includes this broadening while OP perhaps thought it an extension too far), are covered in what I consider to be the duplicate for the IE +(?) comma question. // There are certainly two questions here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Fair enough.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth and JasonBassford: I have trouble following the details... So is a subordinate clause and a dependent clause the same?

Comment: @halloleo Effectively (or even actually), yes. Some people might use the term *subordinate clause* to mean a dependent clause that comes *before* an independent clause (as opposed to a dependent clause that comes after), but both are clauses that cannot stand on their own, and the terms are often used interchangeably.

Comment: After a few rereads, I think that both the 'in my time as' and the 'in my capacity as'  senses are possible readings, without further context, and that probably the 'while' reading is the default one. The 'verbless clause' interpretation is one interpretation.