# Commas - academic text

Tags: grammar, punctuation

Are commas below correct, please?

*In the solution, we except*

*From the beginning, we search for*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comma after introductory phrases](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52091/comma-after-introductory-phrases) kiamlaluno's answer is (alternative style-guides' demands being ignored) definitive. Of course, academic institutions may require adherence to such differing style choices, but the only answer then is to consult the relevant authority. ELU deals with standard ... er ... standards.

Comment: It's not easy to comment on those incomplete sentences. In the first one is there *something else* following, that is excepted, or is it the *solution* which is excepted? In the second, is it *the beginning* which we search for, or something not yet stated?

Comment: Hm. I take back the 'definitive' part. The next answer made a lot of sense, too.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth thanks it helps

Comment: Context needed.

Comment: *We except*, itself, is wrong. It should either be *we accept* or *we excepted* (although both would still be unusual).

Answer (score 1):

The commas are correct.  The spelling of "except" is worrisome.  If you are using "except" as a verb following "we", the spelling should be "accept".  For example, "in the solution, we accept that x is a constant."  The word "except" means to omit or not to include something such as "we, except for Bill, all went to the store."

Comment: What if it's referring to the solution that was excepted?

Comment: @Hot Licks    Yes, it is true that except could indeed be a verb in that instance.  Context or rest of the sentence is indeed needed.

Comment: @HotLicks It would need to be in the past tense. The passive sense of excluding something isn't used in the present tense.

Comment: @JasonBassfordSupportsMonica - It is excepted in this journal article.  Therefore the present tense is appropriate.

Comment: @HotLicks  By past tense I am referring to the formation of the verb: **excepted**, not **except**. When is the last time you ever read a sign saying "buses except"?

Comment: @JasonBassfordSupportsMonica - I've never seen a sign saying "buses excepted".  But in technical writing it's common to describe the currently-discussed subjects in present tense.

Comment: @JasonBassfordSupportsMonica -  Encyclopaedia Britannica:  While the heroism of the Montenegrins has been lauded by writers of all countries, the Albanians - if **we except** Byron's eulogy of the Suloits - still remain unsung.

Comment: @HotLicks Here's [one example](https://live.staticflickr.com/7415/9089803829_8d3469ff36_b.jpg). And [here's another](https://www.flickriver.com/photos/philipmallis/48651729886/). It's also used for taxis, bicycles, and days and hours of the week. It's at least everywhere in Canada and, from what I just found, Australia. I still have no idea how anybody could say *X except*. *Except for X*, yes. But that's a different construction.

Comment: @JasonBassfordSupportsMonica - Yeah, but those Canajians talk weird.