# Comma after to verb

Tags: commas, formality

Should be a comma here? I read this sentence in a book, and it seems to be a little strange without a comma. Or is it only a style? And is the place of **now** right, considering the word order? Is this beginning of the sentence formal and appropriate for academic style? Thank you

> To go further[,] we will need **now** to apply ...

Comment: The comma would be usual, especially with a lengthy continuation, though not mandatory. The first two hits in a Google search for ["to go further we will need"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22To+go+further%5B%2C%5D+we+will+need%22&rlz=1C1ASRM_enGB617GB618&oq=%22To+go+further%5B%2C%5D+we+will+need%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.1598j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) contrast stylewise. // One assumes that the sentence doesn't finish with 'apply', though whether 'apply' is transitive or not is not indicated (this would be useful). Placing _now_ after rather than before _need_ is rather unusual and formal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comma after introductory words, phrases, clauses: unacceptable, obligatory or optional?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52091/comma-after-introductory-words-phrases-clauses-unacceptable-obligatory-or-op) Scanning researched answers, commas are usual after most 'introductory elements' (in this case, a to-infinitival clause), but may be / are often dropped if the intro is short (though to-infinitivals may be less obliging here).

Comment: Thank you very much