# Comma usage in introductory sentences like "for the first two years"

Tags: commas

My Office Word programme says that a comma is required in both the following sentences where included (according to Word, these use *introductory 'sentences'*). However, as English learners, we are unsure in our group whether it is neccessary in each of these sentences.

- (1) *For the first two years of doing business, we generated our income
  through a commission we charge on every order.*
- (2) *With the extension towards more business partners, we estimate dramatically raising costs as well as turnovers.*

We appreciate your help. Thank you in advance.

Greetings from Germany.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comma after introductory words, phrases, clauses: unacceptable, obligatory or optional?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52091/comma-after-introductory-words-phrases-clauses-unacceptable-obligatory-or-op) The bottom line is that it's not mandatory in all examples. However, omitting it sometimes leads to ambiguity, and more often leads to difficulty in parsing. I'd say it's up to the writer in your first example (though a rule of thumb is to always include it for introductory strings of 5 words or more), but nigh-on essential in your second example.

Comment: ... Note that you are likely to come across more prescriptive treatments, style guides (or even grammars) perhaps saying "A comma is needed after introductory elements ('Word' apparently misnames these)"; this is an (even cruder) rule of thumb only and should be acknowledged as such. // I'm afraid I have to highlight my answer (or rather Kolln's article) at the duplicate; the others are useful, but don't mirror actual usage totally faithfully. Again, overly prescriptive.