# Do I need the comma after the opening adjective?

Tags: adjectives, commas, sentence-patterns

The sentence is:

> There, it continues to attract visitors.

vs

> There it continues to attract visitors.

I saw the second example on the grammar section of a standardized test and I thought they made a mistake.

Edit:
I don't remember the context but it's something like:

> The statue was relocated to New York. There...

Comment: Could you quote the entire paragraph, if it isn't too much trouble?

Comment: sure, see the edit

Comment: Related, but not addressing this actual example ('there' is not an adjective; perhaps it's best to stick with 'distal locative'): [use of a comma after an introductory word, phrase or clause – unacceptable, obligatory or optional?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52091/comma-after-introductory-words-phrases-clauses-unacceptable-obligatory-or-op) As with most short intros, the comma here is optional IMO. The sentence is unusual, literary-sounding  (though totally acceptable) and the writer can choose whether to insert a more pronounced pause or not.

Comment: Erm, which adjective?

Comment: BTW, commas are not part of English grammar; they're determined by publishers and editors, not linguists.

Answer (score 0):

It is optional. You don't have to, but you could (i.e. use a comma).

Punctuation depends heavily on intonation, inflection, and all the test of it.

If there's a long enough pause after a word, the rule of thumb is a comma might be advisable to indicate it.